# Expo create local android release

Tags: react-native, expo

I followed the steps from the [here](https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/build-locally/) to test the update function in expo.
The command `npx expo run:android --variant release` returns an error.

> Task :app:createReleaseExpoManifest FAILED
> The command "[node" is either misspelled or
> could not be found.
> w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build\kotlin\sessions

node is installed with version v18.17.0

```
package.json
 "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~49.0.11",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.7.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.13",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.22.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.10"
  },
```

running on windows 10.
project is empty, created with `npx create-expo-app` 1 minute before.

Any idea how to resolve it?
new version broken?
documentation outdated?
missing dependency?